# Ionic 6 capacitor 4 iOS app TinyMCE editor referer header missing issue

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, tinymce, capacitor

I created an iOS app using Ionic 6, Capacitor 4, and Angular 15. TinyMCE editor has a referer header missing issue in the iOS app (see screenshot attachment)

For the editor, I used the "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "7.0.0" npm package.

I tried the following solutions but they didn't work:

1. Added the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key with a value of true in the Info.plist file
2. Added NSAppTransportSecurity and NSExceptionDomains in the Info.plist file
3. Added "data-referrer": "http://example.com" option in the editor init config
4. Added "referrer" meta in the index.html file - added script

How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please dont use images for text information

Comment: You have improved the question so thats good.   The image serves a purpose but the error could be entered in as text.  I have made the image inline and reduced its size. and upvoted

Comment: @RohitGupta I'm here to find a solution